# X-Editable _POST method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using X-Editable and I want to pass a simple value to other page using the _post method and I receive this error:

Notice: Undefined index: first_name in ...

Here my code:

this is a simple html page that have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
    <a href="#" id="first_name" data-type="text" data-url="/post" data-title="Edit First Name" class="editable editable-click">BILL GATES</a>
</form>
```

Here my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//First Name
$('#first_name').editable({         
    validate: function(value) {
   //Not Empty  
       if($.trim(value) == '') return 'The First Name is required';

       //More than 3 and less than 20
       if($.trim(value.length) <4) return 'The First Name must be more than 3 and less than 20 characters';
       //Less than 20
       if($.trim(value.length) >20) return 'The First Name must be more than 3 and less than 20 characters';           
    }
});
```

And here I want to capture the value in the php code:

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
echo $first_name."<br>";
```

and I receive this:

> Notice: Undefined index: first_name in ...

Please any advice or suggestion?

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

In X-editable by default you can pass 3 values (id, name, value)

you can add like this

```
<a href="#" id="first_name" data-type="text" data-url="/post" data-title="Edit First Name" class="editable editable-click" data-name="some_name_here" data-pk="exiting_table_pk">BILL GATES</a>
```

or

```
$('#first_name').editable({
  pk: 1,
  url: '/post',
  name: 'some_name_here',
  title: 'Enter First Name'
});
```

Refer : http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html